# jQuery - IF IN String or Array Condition

Tags: jquery, html-select, custom-attributes

With Jquery, I'm looping through the attribute named `tags`, in each `<option>` of the `<select>` dropdown below.

You'll see I would LOVE to have 2 of the options preselected, if the number 6 exists in the `tags` attribute.

```
<select name="someFun" id="someFun"  multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1" tags="4,6,7">something</option>
  <option value="44" tags="2">something</option>
  <option value="61" tags="1,3,6">something</option>
  <option value="44" tags="2">something</option>
</select>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  var preselectedtag = '6'; // auto select any with 6

  $("#someFun > option").each(function() {
     var tag = $(this).attr("tags");

     /* change attr of this option to "selected" if 6 exists in var tag */

  });

});
</script>
```

I could use some help here. Is there a best way to do this?
In PHP I normally use an in_array() function, but javascript seems way more picky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has an [`inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function:

```
var tags = $(this).attr("tags").split(",");
if ($.inArray(preselectedtag, tags) > -1) {
  alert("Tag " + preselectedtag + " detected!");
}
```

**Edit**

Refactored version of OP's code that selects the detected option tags:

```
$(function(){
  var preselectedtag = '6',
      selected = [];
  $("#someFun > option").each(function() {
    var n = $(this), 
        tags = n.attr("tags").split(",");
    if ($.inArray(preselectedtag, tags) > -1) {
      selected.push(n.val());
    }
  });
  $('#someFun').val(selected);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zFBVT/

Comment: +1 You could add `$(this).attr('selected', 'selected')` to select the options.

Comment: $(this).attr('selected', 'selected') appears to not work.  Or it's selected everything.  How do I select that single option, while iterating through all of them?

Answer (score 1):

What about splitting it by `,` and checking?

```
var tags = tag.split(",")
if(tags.indexOf("6")!==-1){
    //do whatever manipulation you desire
}
```